# Is an egg's prize different each time?

Tags: patapon-2

I want to know if playing with the same egg on one hundred different occasions gives you completely different prizes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And do I have the answer for **You!**

According to [Patapedia](http://patapon.wikia.com/wiki/Masks_and_Eggs), you can get up to 4 masks per egg. After you receive the 4 masks, you just get supplies (meats, weapons, stones, etc.) There are a lot of eggs, so there a vast option of masks to choose from.

Mind that each time you get a mask from an egg, the next mask you get from the same egg is a stronger version of the same mask, up to 4 masks per egg.